# How to extract GET form data in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, form-data

The following code is my form html:

```
<form method="get" action="new_name">
  <input  type="name" required="" maxlength="50" name="username" >
  <button  type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

This submit button produce `http://localhost:8080/new_name?username=hai`

How can I extract the value of `username` from the url in an Express server?

Comment: As you are using express you can access it as `req.query.username`

Comment: req.body will give you the data

Comment: You should take a look at the docs [express: req.query](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query)

Comment: @vibhor1997a thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
app.get('/new_name', function (req, res, next) {
    var receivedUsername = req.query.username;
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
app.get('/new_name', (req, res, next) => {
    const { username } = req.query; // ?username=hai 
    res.json({ username }); // username is equal to 'hai'
});
```

Answer (score 3):

HTML Code:

It will be same as you are having.

```
<form method="get" action="new_name">
  <input  type="name" required="" maxlength="50" name="username" />
  <button  type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

Node JS Code:

```
app.get('/new_name', function (req, res) {
    var username = req.query.username;
})
```

FYI , if you use post method in html form, then you have to use

```
app.post('/new_name', function (req, res) {
    var username  = req.body.username;
})
```